# Dynamically building LINQ queries for WMI

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

This is the current scenario.

I have a WPF form, where there's a combobox from where one can choose any of the Win 32 classes. Below that, I have a datagrid where one can put one of many of the properties.

For example, for Win32_Volume, one can put in the DeviceID, the DriveLetter, the SerialNumber, etc. They can fill up any number of the properties and then the application has to run a query testing if any object exists in the system matching the criterion/criteria.

Since the user is allowed to fill any number of the properties, I am having a hard time building the query.

What I have tried:

Here is what I have tried up till now.

I have built a dictionary with the PropertyName as the key and the user-inputs as the value.

The code-behind is like this:

```
private ManagementObjectCollection GetObjectsOfClass(string classname)
        {            
            var objectcollection = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM " + classname).Get();
            return objectcollection;
        }

private ManagementObject GetObject(string classname, Dictionary<string,string> conditions)
        {
            var query = GetObjectsOfClass(classname).Cast<ManagementObject>();

            foreach(var condition in conditions)
            {
                query = query.Where(test => test.Properties[condition.Key].Value.ToString().Contains(condition.Value));                
            }

            return query.FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

GetObject takes the classname and the dictionary containing the Propertyname, value tuples. Then it gets all the instances of the class and then runs a LINQ query on them.

Do note that I just want one instance matching the criteria, hence the `FirstOrDefault()`.

However this approach has a rather obnoxious code smell. Is there any way I can ditch this dictionary and foreach loop and get the entire procedure done using LINQ only?

Comment: I think it is fine. You can get rid of the `foreach` by using linq `conditions.Select...` but it will make the code harder to read. So I would keep what you have.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Expression Trees](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637(v=vs.100).aspx) Don't know if it will make you code clean but it can make it faster. And I found it super fun to play with.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the direction of Expression Trees. That's a really novel concept.